# cannot invoke initalizer fot type "closure" with no arguments

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a question. the closure can't init.

```
typealias jumpClosureBage = (_ num: Int) -> Void
var jump = jumpClosureBage?()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIAXa.png)

how can I solve it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, closure types cannot have initializers.

And `Optional` does not have an initializer with no argument.

You can initialize it with `nil`:

```
var jump: jumpClosureBage? = nil
```

Or you can initialize it with do-nothing closure:

```
var jump: jumpClosureBage? = {_ in}
```